# Add a suffix string to end of each line?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed, grep

I have two files:

file01:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

file02:

```
A
B
C
```

And I want to get

```
line1 A
line2 B
line3 C
```

I could possibly write a Perl script but it is better if I don't need to.

I have tried using the obvious 
grep -o  '^' file02  >> file01

But this produces

```
line1
line2
line3
A
B
C
```

It should be a simple thing to do, but have not found it in the "man grep" (manual for grep).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is "zip" two files together, use the `paste` command

```
 paste -d ' ' file01 file02
```

Answer (score 4):

As [suggested by @1-cr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80758/22222) The `paste` command is the best way to do this. Here are some other options for the sake of completion:

1. [Bash and file descriptors](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/reading-multiple-files-bash) (adapted from [here](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/146731-read-two-text-files-bash.html)):

   ```
   exec 3<file02
   while read foo; do
    read -u3 bar;
    echo $foo $bar;
   done < file01
   exec 3>&-
   ```

   Here, I am creating a file descriptor called `3` that reads from `file02`. I then use `read`'s `-u` option to read the variable `bar` from the file descriptor `3`. Finally, a normal `while` loop reads `foo` from `file01`.
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -ne 'BEGIN{open($fh,"file02");@a=<$fh>} 
       chomp; print "$_ $a[$.-1]"' file01
   ```
3. `awk`/`gawk`

   ```
   gawk 'BEGIN{f=ARGV[1]}
        {
         if(FILENAME==f){a[FNR]=$0}
         else{print a[FNR],$0}
        }' file01 file02
   ```

Comment: +1. For the sake of completeness you may want to close the file descriptor at the end using `exec 3>&-` in your `read` example